# Battlefield 3 time per class

Tags: battlefield-3

Although the stats page has a nice little pie chart, is there some way to work out exactly how much time you have played as each class...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes there is.

Go to:

> Multiplayer > Leaderboards > Jump to Leaderboard > [Insert Kit Here]

Alternatively:

> Multiplayer > Leaderboards > Kit > [Insert Kit Here]

You can also do very similar for vehicles.

Comment: note that time spent in vehicles is *not* included in these class stats for some bizarre crazy reason. Time spent in a vehicle is "classless"

Comment: You could also go to your award screen and select the (kit) service medal and check your progress towards it if you're feeling daring.